# (.net) Intermediate language exe editor?

Tags: c#, .net, decompiling

I know we have ILdasm, but is there any tool out there that will let me edit .exe or .dll files without having to go through all the *rigmarole* of having to convert it to IL code, with resources includeded, etc etc, manually edit, then recompile again?

Comment: Yea, he does, he has to go through us Leppie to get his answer ;)

Comment: Why the negative rating? its a genuine question.

Comment: I was wondering myself actually.

Comment: question is genune but in hate speech, isn't it?

Comment: Removed the offending portion. Nevertheless, any negative votes this question gets would still be well deserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to disassemble whole namespaces to source code (not IL), but then you're still stuck without a direct editor, you have to copy/paste to a code file and recompile.

On the other hand, it seems like I was wrong, Reflector has an add-in [Reflexil](https://sourceforge.net/projects/reflexil/) that looks like it'll do what you want.

Comment: From what I understand, Reflexil only allows you to do things at run-time, which is not what I am after.

Comment: Ah, seems this is a new version. I'll check it.

Answer (score 1):

check out this SourceForge project I guess it's what you're looking for:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should check out [Mono.Cecil](http://mono-project.com/Cecil). It's a managed library for manipulating IL. You can add, remove and modify methods as you please.

Granted it's not an IDE or anything but it should be a starting point.